# Understanding Rolle's theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

I think this is a very basic question but somehow I am unable to understand the answer.

---

> Find the number of zeroes of $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$.

---

Answer in the book :

$f^\prime (x) = 3x^2 + 1$ since $3x^2 + 1 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ therefore $f^\prime (x) \ge 1 $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Therefore by Rolle's theorem $f(x)$ has at most one zero in its domain.

Now $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(0) = 1$  therefore by Intermediate value theorem $f(x)$ has at least one zero in the interval $[-1, 0]$.

Thus $f(x)$ has one zero.

---

> Rolle's theorem : A function which is continuous $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, then there exist at least a point $c \in [a,b]$ for which $f^\prime(c) = 0$

In the first part of the proof I am unable to understand how Rolle's theorem is applied because we don't know any $a,b$ where $f(a) = f(b) = 0$  .

How can conclude that $f(x)$ has at most one zero ?

Comment: If $f$ had (at least) two zeros then Rolle's theorem would imply that $f'$ has a zero. But your initial calculation shows that $f'$ has no zero.

Comment: When proving an implication of the form $P => Q$ you don't need to first prove that $P$ is true. Hence it is irrelevant that you are not able to find $a$ and $b$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.

Comment: @JohnColeman can you state P and Q in context of my question ?

Comment: $P$ is $f$ has at least two roots. $Q$ is some contradiction (involving $f'$ having a zero when it is known to be nonzero). You are trying to prove that $P$ is *false* by contradiction, hence the fact that you can't prove it true is irrelevant. *Of course* you can't prove it true, because it isn't.

Comment: @MartinR I also thought so but don't we need to satisfy the conditions for Rolle's theorem before applying it ? that is where I am kind of stuck.

Comment: You need to be able to engage in hypothetical reasoning. *If* $f$ had at least two roots, say $a$ and $b$, *then* something nonsensical follows. I can reason like "If the Loch Ness Monster exists then it lives in Scotland" without worrying about the fact that I lack good photographs of said beastie.

Comment: @JohnColeman Ok so we assumed that $f$ statisfies Rolle's theorem and then we proved by contradiction that it does not, thus it must have less than 2 zeroes ?

Comment: Since Rolle's theorem is a theorem all functions satisfy it. I think you mean if we assume that the $f$ satisfies the *assumptions* of Rolle's theorem (which it clearly does if it has two roots) then the *conclusion* of Rolle's theorem leads to something impossible. If you really have trouble following the logic, perhaps this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes I mean assumptions of Rolle's theorem. So in this proof we assumed that there are more than 2 roots of $f$ so by invoking Rolle's theorem we said that $f^\prime$ is zero somewhere. Then we proved that last statement is wrong which implies that our assumption is wrong and thus $f$ does not have 2 zeroes.

Comment: @JohnColeman Is my thinking correct ?

Comment: Yes, basically correct, but I don't think that you meant more than two roots. Phrase it rather as more than one or at least two. You should be able to finish the problem now.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes I always miss that equal to sign, sorry. If you have time and you don't mind can you write an answer ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, as a college math teacher I never give anything more than hints on questions which are clearly homework. Have confidence. You seem to understand the main point now.

Comment: @JohnColeman I just said because I don't like to leave my questions  unanswered. Anyway thanks for the answer .

Comment: @A---B I have made a [post on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/tag-management-2017/26073#26073) about recently created (rolles-theorem) tag. (Although it might worth discussing tags named after theorems in general.) If you have some comments about this, feel free to post on meta or in the [tagging chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the function has two zeros, then by Rolle, $f'(x)$ must be zero for some real number $c$ strictly between the two roots. This is impossible, since $f'(x) > 0$ for all real $x.$ So, the function has at most one zero.To show it has a zero, note that $f(-1) < 0$ and $f(0)>0,$ and appeal to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I already got the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My edit was to change $f'(x)\geq 0$ to $f'(x)>0$. Likely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is always positive, so the function is monotonically increasing, hence it will have one root at most if the minimum value is  less than 0.

Comment: I guess your answer is correct but it does not help me as it does not solve my concerns.