# Why Rolle's theorem gives me wrong answer?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

> Find number of zeroes of $f(x) = 1 - x^{-2}$.

---

I assume that this function has two or more zeroes in the domain $ \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Since $f^\prime (x) = \large{2\over x^3}$, therefore we can say      $f^\prime(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in   \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Therefore by Rolle's theorem we can say that our assumption is wrong (because if it was correct then for any two zeroes $a,b\in\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, $f^\prime(c) = 0$ where $c \in [a, b]$)  and  $f(x)$ has one zero at most in $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

What we deduced is incorrect given the fact that $f(\pm 1) = 0$ and $\{\pm 1\} \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Here I followed [a similar proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186743/understanding-rolles-theorem/2186848#2186848).

---

What is the error in my proof ?

Comment: There could be one zero on each side of 0 (in fact, there is).

Comment: The function is not continuous. '

Comment: Look at the conditions on Rolle's Theorem - the function has to be continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: The hypothesis of Rolle's Theorem requires a closed interval [a,b] such that f is continuous on [a,b], differentiable on (a,b), and f(a) = f(b) = 0. What's your closed interval [a,b]?

Comment: @lulu The function is even everywhere differentiable (where defined), so it's obviously continuous (where defined). The fact it's not defined at $0$ doesn't make it not continuous.

Comment: @lulu Why it is not continuous ? I choose $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ as the domain.

Comment: @A---B: What's your closed interval [a,b]? If you don't have one, forget about using Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Rolles' Theorem requires continuity on the interval between the zeroes.  Here's a simpler example:  take $g(x)=x+1$ for $x≤0$ and $g(x)=x-1$ for $x>0$.  Here $g'(x)=1$ wherever it is defined, but the function has two zeroes.

Comment: @quasi Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186743/understanding-rolles-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1. I took a similar approach.

Comment: @A---B: But I asked for a closed interval [a,b]. Look at the _hypothesis_ of Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: @quasi Look at the third line of the proof. The thing in the brackets. I do know the hypothesis for Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @A---B: If you can't satisfy the hypothesis of Rolle's Theorem, you can't apply the theorem.

Comment: Just to say, the function in that earlier question is $g(x)=x^3+x+1$ which is continuous on the whole of $\mathbb R$, hence if $g(a)=0=g(b)$ we know that $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  That reasoning does not work for the function here, as it is not continuous at $0$.  You can apply your argument to show that $f(x)$ can't have two roots which are both greater than $0$ or both less than $0$.

Comment: @A---B: Show me the closed interval [a,b] for which the hypothesis of Rolle's Theorem is satisfied. If you can't, then that dramatizes your error -- you tried to apply a theorem without checking that the hypothesis was satisfied.

Comment: @lulu The function should be continous on its domain, right ? I took the domain as $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, and $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ does not have any $0$ to check continuity for.

Comment: @A---B: Sure, f is continuous (and differentiable) on its domain, but still, you don't have a closed interval [a,b] on which the hypothesis of Rolle's Theorem is satisfied. There's no getting away from that logical gap. Note: By definition, a closed interval [a,b] is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Look up the statement of [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem).  If $f(a)=0=f(b)$ AND $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, then we can find $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$.  Your function is simply not continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @quasi Ok I get it, my proof is flawed because my function is not continous on $[-1, 1]$ where it has its zeroes. I still did not get why my function should be continous on a clsosed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ even if it is not defined there.

Comment: Because the hypothesis requires it, it's that simple. In particular, if $f$ is required to be continuous on $[a,b]$, it must be defined on _all_ points of $[a,b]$, where by $[a,b]$, we mean _all_ _real_ _numbers_ between $a$ and $b$ inclusive, not just those in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Discontinuities matter!   Go back to my (simpler) example of $g(x)$ which has derivative $1$ but which is discontinuous at $0$. The function is locally monotone increasing....meaning $b>a\implies g(b)>g(a)$ PROVIDED $g(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  The discontinuity at $0$ messes all that up, so there is no problem having $g(1)=0=g(-1)$.

Comment: @lulu, Quasi Yes, thanks for the answer it is a big relief to know my mistake. If you have time and you don't mind can you write an answer.

Comment: I'll defer to lulu on this -- lulu's comment "Look up the statement of Rolle's Theorem ..." is pretty much a complete answer.

Comment: @quasi Yes it pretty much is. Calculus is much more harder than I thought, it is easy to mess up completely on small things. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rolle's theorem works on *intervals*, while $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is not an interval.

Comment: A---B: lulu already explained that -- check back in the comments of the main question (the comment which mentions $x^3 + x + 1$).

Comment: I don't understand upvotes on this answer. I never claimed $\mathbb{R} -\{0\}$ to be an interval, it is not even part of my proof to claim $\mathbb{R} -\{0\}$ as an interval.I think this answer does not answer my question, but what does I know.

Comment: Lulu and Quasi answered my question properly. though I did not downvote this answer and please don't take my comment as a offence to the answerer.

Comment: @A--B This answer addresses your question perfectly. The moment you say "by Rolle's theorem", you are assuming $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ satisfy the hypotheses of Rolle's theorem (and therefore is an interval).